# How to deal with WouldBlock error with a Tokio TcpListener?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Consider the following code:

```
extern crate tokio; // Executor runtime

use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use std::net::SocketAddr;

fn main() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:8118".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap();
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr)
        .expect("unable to bind TCP listener");
    tokio::run(listener.incoming()
        .map_err(|e| eprintln!("failed to accept socket; error = {:?}", e))
        .for_each(|mut socket| {
            let mut buf = vec![];
            socket.read_to_end(&mut buf).unwrap();
            println!("Received: {:#?}", buf);
            Ok(())
        })
    );
}
```

When I run this and send something to port 8118 I get the following error:

```
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker-0' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Kind(WouldBlock)', src/libcore/result.rs:997:5
```

I imagine there is some way to put to put my socket in blocking mode, or perhaps catch the error and do something with it. I wonder what the standard, canonical way to approach this problem is.

I'd rather not block, since I want the server to do other things while waiting for clients, so an async / threaded solution would be fantastic.

Comment: *some way to put to put my socket in blocking mode* — perhaps you don't want to use Tokio, where the entire purpose of it's existence is to allow asynchronous IO...

Comment: I don't want the IO to block the rest of the application, so I want async or threading. More concretely, the server should be able to sit there and listen for stuff (later adding it to a channel) while the rest of the server continues to do stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Tokio, a library where the entire purpose is to enable asynchronous IO. You *never* want to perform blocking operations in the asynchronous event loop.

Instead, either go all-in on async or avoid it completely and use simpler, coarser threads.

Tokio's [`io::read_to_end`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.22/tokio/io/fn.read_to_end.html) creates a future that is capable of reading all the data from a socket:

```
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use tokio::{net::TcpListener, prelude::*}; // 0.1.22

fn main() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:8118".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap();
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr).expect("unable to bind TCP listener");

    tokio::run(
        listener
            .incoming()
            .and_then(|s| tokio::io::read_to_end(s, vec![]))
            .map_err(|e| panic!("failed: {:?}", e))
            .for_each(|(_socket, buf)| {
                println!("Received: {:#?}", buf);
                Ok(())
            }),
    );
}
```

See also:

- [How do I prevent TcpStream from blocking on a read?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557375/155423)
- [Why would the first write to Mio's TcpStream after accepting give an "operation would block" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49886603/155423)
- [What is the standard way to get a Rust thread out of blocking operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52465480/155423)
- [What is the best approach to encapsulate blocking I/O in future-rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41932137/155423)
- [Why does Future::select choose the future with a longer sleep period first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48735952/155423)